# ng2-smart-table - open modal on row click

Tags: angular, smart-table

Angular smart table is using in my project, what I want is to open a popup/modal window for details when clicked on Row.

I'm using like this

```
<smart-table class="table-wrapper" (userRowSelect)="onUserRowSelect($event)" [columns]="columns" [editable]="false" [data]="data"></smart-table>
```

and in component file

```
onUserRowSelect(event) {
    console.log(event);
  }
```

I have googled for this, and the syntax is same but I couldn't make it work.

Comment: Is the table getting displayed at all?

Comment: I got it work, thanks.